# Am I creating my custom ArrayAdapter correctly?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

My ListView populates correctly, but for some reason adding and removing is quirky and does not work properly! Am I doing something wrong?

Set things up in OnCreate()

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        registerForContextMenu(listView); 

        deserializeQuotes();

        if(quotes == null || quotes.size() == 0){
            quotes = new ArrayList<Quote>();
            //populateDefaultQuotes();
            //serializeQuotes();
            //getQuotesFromYQL();
        }

        this.quotesAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(this, R.layout.mainrow, quotes);
        listView.setAdapter(this.quotesAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                deserializeQuotes();
                Quote myQuote = quotes.get(position);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myQuote.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

Quote Adapter Private Class

```
private class QuoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Quote> {

        private ArrayList<Quote> items;

        public QuoteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Quote> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mainrow, null);
            }
            Quote q = items.get(position);
            if (q != null) {
                TextView nameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
                TextView priceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
                TextView changeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.changeText);

                if (nameText != null) {
                    nameText.setText(q.getSymbol());
                }
                if (priceText != null) {
                    priceText.setText(q.getLastTradePriceOnly());
                }
                if (changeText != null) {
                    changeText.setText(q.getChange());
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Remove an item from the list **(THIS DOESNT WORK, DOES NOTHING)**

```
@Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        if(item.getTitle()=="Remove"){
            deserializeQuotes();
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            quotesAdapter.remove(quotes.get(info.position));
            quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            serializeQuotes();
        }  
        else {
            return false;
        }  

        return true;  
    }
```

Add an item to the list (THIS WORKS)

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        deserializeQuotes();
        this.quotesAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(this, R.layout.mainrow, quotes);      
        quotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(quotesAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is how I serialize and deserialize

```
private void serializeQuotes(){
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(Constants.FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(quotes); 
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void deserializeQuotes(){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(Constants.FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            quotes = (ArrayList<Quote>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your "add item" and "remove item" code is the same. A typo?

Comment: I've just spent most of a week battling with similar issues. Have reached the conclusion that ArrayAdapters are just busted, at least for custom types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be alright. Can you try using this in your remove?:

```
if("Remove".equals(item.getTitle())) {
   //....
}
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed you are de-serializing "Quote" objects by calling `deserializeQuotes()`. Have you overridden the `boolean equals(Object)` method of Quote object? When you de-serialize, the object created are not the "same", i.e. they are new objects altogether and if you haven't overridden the equals method:

```
quotesAdapter.remove(quotes.get(info.position));
```

will fail because it won't find any Quote object to remove in the list.

Can you check that?

Comment: Updated the remove code. Equals is more correct. Unfortunately remove still doesn't work properly.

Comment: i over-rode equals() but am I don't use it anywhere in deserialize or serialize. any pointers?

Comment: Override Quote class's equals and hashcode method. arrayadapter.remove compares the objects with equals(), and if matching object is found, it removes that object. Can you post your equals implementation?