# How to make a view appear below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hey I want to make a view appear below the last that has been created.

It is showing like this:

[image]

I want to make the next view show below the last one, so for each new view added, it shows below. Understand?

Here is my code. The xml file and the java file.

**listitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:id="@+id/linearId" 
    android:padding="6dip"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="My Application" 
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout"
            android:textSize="10sp" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**RatedCalls.java**

```
public class RatedCalls extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCalls";
private TableLayout table;
private CallDataHelper cdh;
private TableRow row;
private TableRow row2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listitem);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "calling from onCreate()");

    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);

    startService(new Intent(this, RatedCallsService.class));
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service called.");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "before call fillList");

    List<String> ratedCalls = new ArrayList<String>();
    ratedCalls = this.cdh.selectTopCalls();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearId);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        TextView x = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        x.setText(ratedCalls.get(0));

        TextView ht = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        ht.setText(ratedCalls.get(1));

        ll.addView(item, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work so you need to create two different xml for each inflater

In your layout folder,new xml **layout/main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="My Application"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                />    
        </LinearLayout>
```

Then your **layout/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearId"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/rowCount"    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TextView>
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearId2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"> 
         </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can set you **activity** like this

```
 private int ELEMENTINEACHROW=2 ;
    private int NOOFROW = 4;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearId);
        for (int j = 0; j < NOOFROW; j++) {
            View itemMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
            TextView rowCount = (TextView) itemMain.findViewById(R.id.rowCount);
            rowCount.setText("Row:"+(j+1));
            LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) itemMain.findViewById(R.id.linearId2);
            for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTINEACHROW; i++) {
                View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, null, false);

                TextView x = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                x.setText("test");

                TextView ht = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
                ht.setText("good");

                ll2.addView(item, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            }
            ll.addView(itemMain, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }
    }
```

Hope it give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you should be using listitem.xml from a list adapter. What you're doing is, first setting your content view to an instance of listitem.xml, then trying to insert an instance of listitem INTO listitem's first LinearLayout. You should use listitem.xml as the view that you inflate in your custom adapter's `getView()` method. See the `QuoteAdapter` class from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614934/am-i-creating-my-custom-arrayadapter-correctly) for an example, or just Google search "custom ArrayAdapter Android" for tons of results on this topic.

Comment: Can you give me a more clear example of how to implement this? I didn't understand very well. I created an object of ListAdatpter, but when I try to instantiate it it says it cannot be insantiated. thanks.

Comment: This is one I usually refer people to: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ CommonsWare's book excerpt on ListViews is excellent as well: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try the first link, and later I post an update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, set the `android:orientation` attribute to `vertical` on your `<LinearLayout/>`:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
     android:id="@+id/linearId" 
     android:padding="6dip"
     android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Check out the [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) class documentation and the [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation) documentation for more information.

Comment: You mean on `LinearLayout`, not `ListView`, right? That's not actually the problem with this example though, although it's what I first thought it was. listitem should just be a single view, inserted into another vertical LinearLayout (realistically a ListView is what is needed).

Comment: @kcoppock yeah LinearLayout not ListView. Fixing now

Answer (score 0):

mmm...I did not understand fully what is required, but may be you need to add android:orientation="vertical" to LinearLayout with id="linearId".